Is there a single word that means "type of damage"?
If something burns, it might have "fire damage."
If something has been immersed in water, it might have "water damage."
If something is smashed or cut, it might have "physical damage."
But...I cannot think of any single word in English that specifies "type of damage" generically.  It seems like an insurance company somewhere would have a single word for this on their documentation.
An example of a sentence that might use this word:

Bob had filled this form many times, putting "fire" or "water" into the [WORD] field; this was the first time he had ever heard someone having to write "decompression," though.


Why would the word "damage" itself not work? Damage sounds like the general term that could label a field. Maybe it would be "damages" in plural.

Is this a form for analysing damage for insurance or repair purposes?  If so, why not have a main heading 'damage types' andf then 1. Fire, 2. water, 3  misuse by small five-year-old child with screwdriver 4 ...?

Cause of damage, reason for damage, and type of damage aren't really synonyms. You could make distinctions although maybe not hard and fast ones.

What is the inclination to ask for single words when adjectives serve so well?

If you look at what insurance companies do, they typically ask for description of accident or similar, with a very large space. They want details, not just a vague phrase like "fire damage" or "water damage". They need to know who is responsible and whether it is covered by the policy: severe weather, car ferry sinking, driving off the edge of a pier, being stolen and dumped in a lake, and driving into a fire hydrant may all cause water damage to a car, but the insurance company needs to know the difference.
